# Replication to verify scripts won't break in lower lifecycles

Tags: sql-server, replication

I need to know if there is any danger to setting up transactional/snapshot replication in a QC environment (SQL Server 2005 sadly), with no subscribers - just so we can test deployment scripts for "replication sensitivity".  Recently had a rollout with thousands of scripts, many (21) had drop+create on replicated objects instead of "if not exist create"+alter.  Tired of banging the drum and want to install/configure replication in DEV or QC just as it is used in production, but without any subscribers.  Not sure if having no subscribers has any log file implications.  I don't think it does, but thought I'd ask smarter people.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to set up the subscribers so that you will know when the replication actually breaks.  We set up replication in our QA and PREPROD environments and pointed them to either a second instance of SQL on the same server, or just a second set of databases on the same instance (e.g. REPL_Databasename).

That way when a change is pushed to QA or PRE and replication breaks, you can fix the migration scripts so it won't happen when you push to PROD.

Comment: I typically see DML/DDL in rollouts, so setting up an actual pub/sub repl means > +1TB of data for the subscriber, thus my hope to just set up articles but no subscribers.  Since we are replicating DDL as well (0x0803509F), the problems stem mainly from old drop/creates that keep cropping up.  If there is no safe way to implement replication this way (sort of like installing SQL Server on a single-node cluster), then I'll have to see about getting the disk space for a full-blown repl-setup.  I'll up-vote your answer if no one else steps up regarding my original intent.  Thanks for your help!